# Get data as object after form submit in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, forms

I am building a website that can send custom data after submission with the below code.

```js
$('form').submit((e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = $('form').serializeArray();
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/submit',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Name
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Andi" /><br />
  Password
  <input type="password" name="password" value="pass" /><br />
  Role <br/ >
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="teacher" checked /> Teacher <br />
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="student" /> Student <br />
  Hobby <br/ >
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Sport" checked /> Sport <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Music" /> Music <br />
  Description
  <textarea name="description">I like programming</textarea><br />
  City
  <select name="city">
    <option value="Jakarta">Jakarta</option>
    <option value="Bali">Bali</option>
  </select><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So, to get the data after submission, I use `.serializeArray()` method with returning an array of object data. But the output does not identical to my expectation:

```json
{
  "name": "Andi",
  "password": "pass",
  "role": "teacher",
  "hobby": ["Sport"],
  "description": "I like programming",
  "city": "Jakarta"
}
```

Is there a simple way to get data as JSON Object after submission like the example above?

Comment: manually format? using reduce i guess

Comment: I think the easiest approach is to use the FormData API, as described here: https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/get-form-values-as-json

Comment: @cmgchess Yes, it can, but seems ineffective if there are many data elements.

Comment: @ConradNeumann Nice reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object. You need to loop through all the keys now that you have more values (radio buttons) with the same name. So, if there are more values with the same name/key you get the value as an array (with [getAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll)) otherwise you get the plain text value.

```js
$('form').submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let formdata = new FormData(e.target);
  let data = {};
  [...formdata.keys()].forEach(key => {
    let values = formdata.getAll(key);
    data[key] = (values.length > 1) ? values : values.join();
  });
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/submit',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Name
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Andi" /><br /> Password
  <input type="password" name="password" value="pass" /><br /> Role <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="teacher" checked /> Teacher <br />
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="student" /> Student <br /> Hobby <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Sport" checked /> Sport <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Music" /> Music <br /> Description
  <textarea name="description">I like programming</textarea><br /> City
  <select name="city">
    <option value="Jakarta">Jakarta</option>
    <option value="Bali">Bali</option>
  </select><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this is what you really want but you can try this

```js
$('form').submit((e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();

    const data = Object.fromEntries([...new FormData(this)]);

    console.log(data);

});
```